# Creating two columns from a naming pattern in a single column using pivot_wider

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

I need to create a wider data frame based on a naming pattern in a single string variable and was wondering if there is a neat way to do it using pivot_wider

To data is below

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
d <- tibble(stat = as.vector(sapply(1:3, function(i) paste0(c("mean_", "sd_"), "var", i))),
            score = sample(1:20, 6, replace = T))
```

And looks like this

```
d

#   A tibble: 6 x 2
#   stat      score
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 mean_var1     4
# 2 sd_var1       7
# 3 mean_var2     1
# 4 sd_var2       2
# 5 mean_var3    11
# 6 sd_var3      14
```

I would like to transform the data so it looks like this

```
#    var mean sd
# 1 var1    4  7
# 2 var2    1  2
# 3 var3   11 14
```

Is there a way to do this using `pivot_wider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some pre-processing before getting data in wide format :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

d %>%
  mutate(var = str_extract(stat, 'var\\d+'), 
         stat = str_remove(stat, paste0('_', var))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = stat, values_from = score)

#  var    mean    sd
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 var1      4     7
#2 var2      1     2
#3 var3     11    14
```